# Select and modify node, keeping the rest unchanged with xlst

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <SECTION>
        <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
            <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
                <TOKEN BEGIN="9" END="11" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="32" END="37" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="167" END="169" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="210" END="215" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
            </SENTENCE>
            <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="2">
                <TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="143" END="145" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="B" />
            </SENTENCE>
            <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
                <TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />                    
            </SENTENCE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
    </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

And I need to obtain the following result, with the node `TOKEN` selected by the `IF` statement, updated with the attribute `NEW`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <SECTION>
        <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
            <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
                <TOKEN BEGIN="9" END="11" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="32" END="37" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="167" END="169" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="210" END="215" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
            </SENTENCE>
            <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="2">
                <TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
                <TOKEN BEGIN="143" END="145" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="B" />
            </SENTENCE>
            <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
                <TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" NEW="YES" />
                <TOKEN></TOKEN>
            </SENTENCE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
    </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Using the following XSLT transformation I obtain a wrong result, where the node `TOKEN` selected by the IF statement is copied at the beginning of the tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
  <xsl:key name="primary_tokens" 
    match="SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN" 
    use="concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END)"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//TOKEN[@DOUBLE='YES'][key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))]">
      <xsl:if test="key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))[@BEGIN > current()/@BEGIN]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="NEW">YES</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unwanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TOKEN NEW="YES" BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />
<DOCUMENT>
  <SECTION>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="9" END="11" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="32" END="37" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="167" END="169" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="210" END="215" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="143" END="145" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="B" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
  </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I came up with a possible solution, adding in `xsl:template` the `match="//SECTION/PARAGRAPH/SENTENCE[@NAME='SECONDARY']/TOKEN` condition. Unfortunately even this solution is not correct, because the content `TOKEN`node is simply copied in the `SENTENCE` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
  <xsl:key name="primary_tokens" 
    match="SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN" 
    use="concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END)"/>
  <xsl:template match="//SECTION/PARAGRAPH/SENTENCE[@NAME='SECONDARY']/TOKEN">
    <xsl:for-each select="current()[key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))]">
      <xsl:if test="key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))[@BEGIN > current()/@BEGIN]">


            <xsl:attribute name="NEW">YES</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>


      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Wrong output with `TOKEN` in `SENTENCE` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DOCUMENT>
  <SECTION>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="9" END="11" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="32" END="37" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="167" END="169" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="210" END="215" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="143" END="145" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="B" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1" NEW="YES" BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />
        <TOKEN />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
  </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

My question is: How do I obtain the wanted result reported above? Is my second try any close to a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your second try is close; you do want to match `TOKEN` if that's what you want to update.

Try this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="primary_tokens" 
    match="SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN" 
    use="concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TOKEN[@DOUBLE='YES']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))[@BEGIN > current()/@BEGIN]">
        <xsl:attribute name="NEW">YES</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpX